# Old short sport story that involved students putting on helmets or visors that projected what they imagined at their opponents

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I've looked all over but can't find an answer. This is me last hope.

One of our elementary school textbooks (Canada) around the late '90s, early 2000s had a collection of short stories. One of them was Lose Now, Pay Later by Carol Farley; easy enough to find. The one I can't find was a sports story.

I remember it involved students putting on helmets (or visors?) that projected what they imagined at their opponents. If their opponents couldn't return, remake, or change what they sent over (for example, flinging a meteor at your opponent and they deflect it into the ocean), you'd get a point. But points were docked for excessive violence and whatnot. The imagination sparring became so popular that it upended the "social hierarchy" in schools; making imaginative geeks more popular than jocks.

I'm sorry I can't recall the plot, all I remember is that the protagonist was one of these players, and their best friend or some-such was not. I'd love to reread it because it was such a novel concept, and any help in identifying the story would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _Lose Now, Pay Later_ has only been published in the anthology [2041: Twelve Short Stories About the Future](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?354697) edited by Jane Yolen. Do any of the other titles listed in that link look like your story?

Comment: There's a copy of 2014 [on the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/isbn_9780385304450/mode/2up). I skimmed it and none of the stories match your description. The publication history of _Lose Now, Pay Later_ on the ISFDB must be incomplete.

Comment: I found a copy of _Lose Now, Pay Later_ in an educational anthology called [The SciFi Factor](https://archive.org/details/scififactor0000unse/mode/2up) but again none of the other stories match your description.